# Package library in the final exec file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, packaging, bundle

I'm developping with visual studio 2008 and I use several project library used by several application project. There is also external dependency.

When I distribute the program, all the DLL appears in the program files folder which would make very easy to hack my program.
Is is possible to bundle all the project library into one exec file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you sign your assemblies it will be near impossible to "hack" your program. Read about signing assemblies [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx). There is a program called ILMerge that you can use to bundle your assemblies into one, but I don't see the need really... at least not to avoid that someone hacks your codez :-)

Comment: Thanks! you've answered my question and gave me a better clue to do it!
I will post another question relating to code obfuscation with signed assembly, that should be enough to protect my application correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. There is a tool called ILMerge. For more info see http://blogs.msdn.com/brad_mccabe/archive/2005/08/19/453703.aspx